# How to solve the issue ,'where' is not recognized as internal or external command?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I am using Flutter in IntelliJ but Now when I am creating a new Flutter project it shows me the error `where is not recognized as an internal or external command` and saying me to run `flutter doctor`.[image]
[image]
[image]

WHAT I HAVE TRIED.

I have tried to add the path of where.exe ( i.e `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe`) to the environmental variable as someone suggested [here](https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter?at=5932a433f2dd2dba0665c5c4)

Comment: Which version of Windows is happening on?

Comment: Windows 10 sir.

Comment: I've not seen that error with Flutter on Windows 10. It looks like your system is not finding the where executable, but the only thing I could suggest is adding it to your system path, which it looks like you've already tried.

Comment: Yup I had tried that.but no success :(

Answer (score 0):

This looks like that the Flutter SDK installed on the machine has issues. It's best to do a [clean install](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk) of Flutter to reconfigure the SDK again.